# Game maker language - Loops

Tags: loops, gml

Been working on a program that is suppose to Loop and display 13 times. Here is my code

```
 { 
var count; 
var user_Input;
var output_msg;
var cel;
count = 0;

   do 
      { 
        user_Input = get_integer("Temperature conversion","");
        count = count + 1;
        cel = user_Input * 9/5 +32;
        user_Input = user_Input +10;
        output_msg =(string(count) + "Celsius" + string(user_Input) + " = Farenheit " + string(cel));
        show_message(output_msg);
        } 
         until (count == 13)

 }
```

What It Does is it Displays the loop each time I hit enter instead of showing all 13 at once also if i enter 10 for example each time it loops its suppose to add 10 from the last loop. 
eg. 1. Celsius 10 = Farenheit (answer here)
..... 2. Celsius 20 = Farenheit (answer Here)
 ......13. Celsuis 130 = Farenheit "" 
 if some one could walk me through and help me that would be great

Comment: move the `user_Input = get_integer(...);` line outside the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll have to do is :

1. move the dialog box `show_message` *outside* the loop, well, after the `Do` loop to be precise. Then, it will be displayed only at the end of the loop, while the `get_integer` dialog box will of course wait for the user to enter a value.
2. move the `get_integer` aswell outside the loop, right before it. User will just have to input value once. If you put it inside the loop, you'll be asked to enter a value 13th times...
3. append the resulting calculations to the message to be displayed contained in `output_msg` to ***itself***, with the line feed `"#"` at the end.

---

```
{
    var count = 0;
    var user_Input;
    var output_msg = "";
    var cel;
    count = 0;

    user_Input = get_integer("Temperature conversion","");
    do
        {
        count = count + 1;
        cel = user_Input * 9 / 5 + 32;
        user_Input = user_Input + 10;
        output_msg = (output_msg + string(count) + ". Celsius" + string(user_Input) + " = Farenheit " + string(cel) + "#");
        }
    until (count == 13)
    show_message(output_msg);
}
```

For clarity, I've initialized some variables initial values.

Your issue is not a code issue, it's a logic issue (except for the line feed) Everything inside a loop, (Do, While) will be executed on every iteration. If you don't want something to be executed, you must either move it outside the loop (before/after), or use a condition check.